# Get value from HTML Table Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I want a HTML Table in such a way that I can select only one cell and retrieve it's value so I can use in other operations on my app. The problem is that I have no idea on how to structure the table in a way that only one cell can be selected, the selected cell change it's color and so on. Here's an example so you guys can picture what I have in mind.

[Table selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwN73.jpg)

And here is the hardcoded model of my app:

```
<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR INÍCIO -->
    <nav id="barra_navegacao"class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="jogos.html" title="Início">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="jogos.html" title="Início">
                    <i class="fa fa-bluetooth"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="jogos.html" title="Início">
                    <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="jogos.html" title="Início">
                    <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
                </a>

            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href=""><span class="fa glyphicon-log-out"></span> <small>SAIR</small></a></li>
                </ul> 
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a style="color: red;" href="../config/encerra_acesso.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> <small>SAIR</small></a></li>
                </ul> /-->                   

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVBAR FIM-->



    <!-- PAINEL APOSTAS INÍCIO -->
    <div id="painel_aposta" class="painel-aposta row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="add-on">R$</span>
                <input style="width: 90px;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="5.00" aria-describedby="add-on">
            </div>
            Retorno(R$): <b>0.00</b><br>
            Qtd. Jogos: <b>0</b><br>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button id="finalizar_aposta" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                Atualizar
            </button>

            <button id="finalizar_aposta" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
                onclick="submitForm('form_apostas')">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            Finalizar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PAINEL APOSTAS FIM -->




    <!-- COTAÇÕES INÍCIO -->
    <div id="painel_partidas" class="panel panel-primary panel-heading-margin">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <center>
                <b>Brasil &raquo; Série A</b>
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#partida" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-compress"></i></button>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id="partida" class="panel-heading-margin">


            <table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4" style="width: 100%">
                <tr class="w3-dark-grey">
                    <td>
                        <small>TALLERES ESCALADA x EXCURSIONISTAS</small>
                        <span class="pull-right"><small>08/10 18:00 &nbsp; </small> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></button></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4" style="width: 100%">

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>

            <div id="resultado"></div>

                <!--COTAÇÕES AQUI-->

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- COTAÇÕES FIM -->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/webservice.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript">listaCampeonatos();</script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>-->

</body>
```

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6pGv.png)

I need basically the same thing in the fist screenshot. If someone can enlighten me with some help I'd appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use id or data- attribute in html5

Comment: have you tried say something like - adding a class on the respective cells `onclick` ?

Comment: Ok, but regarding the code to make possible to select the cells.. Could you help me?

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho : check my ans. run the snippet for testing

Comment: Oh, that's a cool tip! Thaks, I'm gonna try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this. i am giving the value in alert. you can just assign the value in a variable and use in your app.
the html table is full yours one, i just added an id to the table. and a css class 'active' to hightlight the click div.
(you need to include the jquery script in you page)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.mytable tbody tr td',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).parents('tbody').find('td').not(this).removeClass('active');
    alert($(this).find('strong').html());
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  background: #999;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="" border='1' class="mytable w3-table-all w3-card-4" style="width: 100%">

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                Casa<br>
                                <strong>2.00</strong>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot! In this case I presented just one table but in the actual app the a lot more will be dinamically generated for each returned row in the bank. So, how can I call the js function you made just once for every generated table?

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho : sorry for late. check my edited ans.  it will work for all dynamically created tables, but u will need to provide the class 'mytable' for all tables.

Answer (score 0):

give an id and use getElementById() to select the cell. Don't use the center tag, its depricated. I am assuming you want to use javascript

Comment: I think it's basically what's happening here: [link](http://artilheiro.me/) but as I'm a beginner I don't actually know how to do it. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
<td id="cell1"></td>
```

then in jQuery

```
$(function() { //this wrapper just tells the script not to run until the whole page is rendered
  $("#cell1").click(function(event) {  //this bit handles any user clicks on cell1
    console.log("clicked cell 1"); 
  });
});
```

will log to the browser console whenever the user clicks it.

If you want to run the same event for multiple cells then give them all a class and select against that instead (e.g. `<td class="myGroup">` and `$(".myGroup").click(...`).

This all uses standard jQuery syntax for binding to browser events - might be worth reading up on the basics of this.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you're looking to get values from the table by clicking on table cells.

For jQuery I would use a delegated approach to adding a click handler to all cells of the table. By using a [delegated](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) approach you are attaching fewer click handlers to the page and it will also work if you dynamically add cells to the table at a later time (i.e. Ajax).

Click on table cells in the Code Snippet to see their value copied to the green box.

```js
var $display = $('.display');

$('.my-table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
  $display.text(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```css
.display {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Aaron</td>
    <td>Anderson</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Beth</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="display"></div>
```

**Note:** As others have noted, the [`<center>` tag is depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Use [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cell1").click(function(){
$(this).css("background-color", "#ccc");   
});
```